# How to get the right submit from a form in a list of forms in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a list of forms in a page of my meteor app, the list is generated dynamically and all the forms have the same class. 
So i made the event submit on the events area of my template, but when i submit the form, only the first form works, if i submit the second form for example, meteor event understand that the event came from the first, and i don'k know how to pass the form id to meteor events, so i can't get the data from the right form. Someone can help me?

This is my event:

```
'submit .form-equation': function (e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = t.find('#name').value,
            equation = t.find('#equation').value,
            order = Number(t.find('#order').value),
            isChart = t.find('#isChart').checked;

        var equationData = {
            name: name,
            equation: equation,
            order: order,
            isChart: isChart
        };

        var station = Stations.findOne(Session.get('stationNewID'));
        var sensorId = t.find('#sensorId').value;

        Meteor.call('insertEquation', station, sensorId, equationData, function (error, result) {
            if (error)
                console.log(error);

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something else wrong with your application. The behavior you described (having multiple forms of the same class with different IDs) works correctly on a clean example.

Check out the demo I made that demonstrates this: http://meteorpad.com/pad/8CPL2xvS7taeL6jZS/MultipleFormSubmitExample

Basically, the forms look like this:

```
<template name="example">
  <form id="1" class="yolo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
  <form id="2" class="yolo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
  <form id="3" class="yolo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
</template>
```

And there is only one event listener:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'submit .yolo': function (e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($(e.target).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, your example solves my problem. I was getting the value of fields using target only, and not the event.target, this approach works for a single form, but not in a list of forms, so the correct way to get the values is $(e.target).find('#name').val();